# How should an address be formatted for global sales

Tags: html, street-address

I'm trying to write an HTML form for entering your address, but I'm a bit stuck.  At the moment it's for UK only, but starting to get global sales.  There is a dropdown for county and a dropdown for country...but other countries don't neccessarily have a county

What fields should be on an address form which needs to be valid globally?

Answer (score -1):

- Billing address
- City
- State or Province
- Zip or Postal code
- Country

Comment: Not all countries have states or provinces (or they are not meaningful in addresses).

Answer (score -1):

I suggest looking at http://www.addressdoctor.com/en/countries_data/addressformats.asp and examining the default format for the main countries you work in. I worked in the direct-mail industry for several years - standardization can sometimes be difficult.